# formating and conditionals in python

Tags: string, if-statement, format

Here's my assignment:

Using a combination of `raw_input()`, `if`, `elif`, and `else`, write a program that asks the user their blood pressure. 
Compare the blood pressure against the following chart and save the Status to a variable named `BP_STATUS`. At the end of the program, print a nice sentence with a formatting string to tell you your status and use `.format()` to replace the formatting string with your `BP_STATUS`.

Heres what I did:

[image]

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see code in your question, I see "enter image description here"

Comment: What's the problem?  What do you expect it to do?  What does it currently do?  Please post your code as text rather than an image in case somebody helping you wants to try running it themselves.  See this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask a good stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

if int (BP_STATUS) < 89:
    print 'Your status is currently: Low!'

elif int (BP_STATUS) < 119:
    print 'Your status is currently: Ideal!'

elif int (BP_STATUS) < 139:
    print 'Your status is currently: Warning!'

elif int (BP_STATUS) < 159:
    print 'Your status is currently: High!'

else:
    print 'Your status is currently: Emergency!'

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a description of what this code does and how it solves the problem in the question.